# How to add a Euro currency symbol in a PDF in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, unicode, pdf-generation

I am making a PDF file in Objective-C and all goes well. But when I add some curreny symbols in the PDF, it shows something totally different.

**‚Ç†2,060,0 instead of €2,060,0**

I have uses the following code to draw text in a PDF:

```
NSString *reducedString = @"€4,854,525";
CGContextShowTextAtPoint (currentContext,xPos, yPos, [textToDraw UTF8String], [reducedString length]);
```

Anyone knows how to draw the Euro symbol using this same code ? Is there anything I need to change in the text encoding?

```
[reducedString drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(xPos  ,yPos) withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the problems with `drawAtPoint`? Because that should handle the encoding correctly.

Answer (score 5):

Try using the unicode of euro symbol

```
\u20AC
```

Answer (score 1):

Right way to go is needs to use NSNumberFormatter.

```
NSInteger currency = 4345;
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[numberFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
NSString *result = [numberFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:currency]];
```

And result will be string with currency sign depending on the locale.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
//for the document Header
NSString *textToDraw = @"Your text";
UIFont *font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18.0];
CGSize stringSize = [textToDraw sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset, pageSize.height - 2*kBorderInset - 2*kMarginInset) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
//for title
fYheight=fYheight+25;
CGRect renderingRect = CGRectMake(kBorderInset, fYheight, pageSize.width - 2*kBorderInset, stringSize.height);
[textToDraw drawInRect:renderingRect withFont:font lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap alignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
```

Add your text to textToDraw string. No need to convert to constant char.